# Snapseed photo looks different (unedited) when exported

Tags: digital, export

I run a small business and Snapseed was recommended to me as a quick and easy way to whiten the backdrop of my photos. In theory it works great. I make a lot of use of the selective tool to brighten and desaturate the corners of my image. I also sometimes use the "healing" tool to smooth over those same area. I do this all from my iPhone SE, running version 11.2.2.

However, when I export the image it almost looks like not all of my edits get saved. At first I though that it was a problem of one screen vs another as the differences were subtle. The only way I have found to solve this problem is to repeatedly export and then re-edit the image until it looks right exported, which is a giant pain.

I am following the instructions for iPhone users, which say to export as a jpeg rather than saving the image.(https://support.google.com/snapseed/answer/6155519?hl=en )

Please help!

[image: Image in Snapseed]

[image: Same image exported]

Comment: I've run Snapseed on a 6S, iOS 10 and haven't experienced any issues exporting. :-/. I wish that I could help with your software issue. I would, however, recommend you get a lightbox like this: http://orangemonkie.com/foldio3/ Not having to force pure white bg's makes $$ by saving time.

Comment: Hi Corey, Thanks for the tip. Most of my work is larger that these allow for, and I'm betting that big versions are probably pretty costly. Although I end up having my biggest pieces done professionally anyway.... Maybe it's still worth it?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "costly". It's easy enough to make your own though. They're really just well lit pieces of white chloroplast, though you could use anything that's white.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I think I just figured it out.
When you do many edits on an image, including different times using the healing tools, at the end even though the image looks good, some parts get messed up when you export. And what I found out was to delete all the edits I made with the healing tool, and to fix all in only one edit at the end before exporting.
This might be annoying, because you need to do it all again (and in only one shot) but that’s the only solution that worked for me.
Most of the times I don’t have any problems with my edits, but only sometimes.... i think this happens when I « heal » my picture too many times with too many edits... 
I hope it helps!! I actually found this post looking for a solution to the same problem.
Anthony

Comment: Thanks mate - you saved one of my photos! : ) After removing healing changes export works properly. Btw: you don't have to do everything from beginning - you can view all edits in a list and delete healing changes from it.